# Create React App Typescript Absolute Paths Not Working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, path, absolute

I tried to create a new typescript React app using the command:

```
npx create-react-app config-app --template typescript
```

Then, under the *src* directory I created some folders/files so that it looked like the following:

```
-config-app
  -src
    -types
      -maybe.ts
      -nullish.ts
    -utils
      -nullish.ts
```

Both the *maybe.ts* and *nullish.ts* files contain an *export type* operation.

In the *nullish.ts* app it has the following import:

```
 import type { Maybe, Nullish } from 'types'
```

I am getting the error *Cannot find module 'types' or its corresponding type declarations.*  So it seems absolute paths are not working.  I have followed the suggestions on this site to add the *"baseUrl": "src"* and *"include": [ "src" ]* into the *tsconfig.json* file.  I have an older react typescript app for which this was working but it doesn't with this latest template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a index file next to `nullish.ts` and `maybe.ts` and export the types of these files in the index file as follows:

Structure:

```
-config-app
  -src
    -types
      -maybe.ts
      -nullish.ts
      -index.ts
    -utils
      -nullish.ts
```

index.ts content:

```js
export * from './maybe'
export * from './nullish'
```

at last you can import types without error as follows:

```js
import  type  {Maybe, Nullish} from 'types'
```

Comment: This fixed the problem.  Thanks!!!